# Android: topbar + ViewFlipper +scrollview + Bottom Bar

Tags: android

I am creating these items as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">top bar</RelativeLayout>
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3">

            <ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fadingEdge="none" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
edittext and textview

    </ScrollView>

        </RelativeLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout5" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:background="@drawable/bar">
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I click the edittext the softinput mode opens but the bottom bar displays the above of keyboard.

Pls help me. why does the bottom bar display above of keyboard

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try setting [windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) to `adjustPan` in the relevant Activity tag? E.g.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

That should prevent the layout from being resized by the software keyboard.